# Word is trying to recover

Tags: c#, windows, windows-vista, ms-word

We are currently processing big word documents in c# program.
During processing i am getting message "Microsoft Windows has stopped working".

The program reads the word document based on the comments added to the document and processes the images and other text in the document and also creates lot of independent word documents with content from the original document.

What is the reason for the problem? Is this because word documents are created, opened and closed so frequently?

Program Steps:
1) Copy the content referred by the comment in the doc to clipboard

```
    comment.Scope.CopyAsPicture();
```

2) Then process convert the content to "html" or "plain" image by

```
    public String _GetContentFromClipboard()
    {
        String text = "";
        if (Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html) != null)
        {
            text = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                Image image = iData.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true) as Image;
                String imageFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
                image.Save(imageFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                text = "<img src=\"" + imageFile + "\" width=\"" + image.Width + "\" height=\"" + image.Height + "\" />";
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

3) Also sometimes save the content from the clipboard to new word document

```
    public String SaveClipboardContentToDoc(bool removeComments)
    {
        Object docName = GeneralUtil.GetTempFileWithoutExtension() + ".docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        oWord.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        oWord.Visible = false;
        oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
        if (removeComments == true)
        {
            foreach (Comment selectionComment in oDoc.Comments)
            {
                selectionComment.Delete();
            }
        }
        oDoc.SaveAs(ref docName, ref missingObj,
                    ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
                    ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
                    ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)oDoc).Close(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)oWord).Quit(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        return docName.ToString();
    }
```

The initial warning message is

```
"Microsoft Windows has stopped working"
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem and try to recover your information.
Check online for a solution and close the program
close the program
Debug the program

Then clicking on debug leads to " "An unhandled win32 execption occurred in WINWORD.EXE [7372]"
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible but without seeing your code we can only be guessing.

Comment: `Microsoft Windows has stopped working`! Are you sure that is the correct error message?

Comment: I do lot of processing with "Clipboard" and clear the clipboard

Comment: yes, its the error message("Microsoft Windows has stopped working")

Comment: I highly doubt this is the exact error message as usually when Windows stops working you see a blue screen of death or your computer restarts unexpectedly.

Comment: @Thiyaneshwaran S: What application exactly is causing this complete nonsensical error? If Windows stops working you get a BSOD.

Comment: Its a c# program i have written to read the data from MSWord and paste it to clipboard and create new word documents from this clipboard content.

Comment: @Thiyaneshwaran S, I think that without seeing your code you are wasting your time in unuseful comments.

Comment: The error message is "Microsoft Windows has stopped working" and clicked on "Debug" and got another message as "An unhandled win32 execption occurred in WINWORD.EXE [7372]".

Comment: The actual message i got in debugging is "Unhandled exception at 0x662c1173 in WINWORD.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x662c1173".

Comment: How can i post the source code? Its a big file...

Comment: @Thiyaneshwaran S: Ideally you would narrow it down to the smallest amount of code that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Thiyaneshwaran S: Edit your original post, add the debug messages in `code blocks` along with the source code, also in `code blocks`.

Comment: @Thiyaneshwaran S, you don't need to post the whole code of your application, only a small part of it that illustrates the problem. Ideally this part should be standalone so that other people would be able to compile as is. You will notice that if you do this systematically you will find the problems yourself and won't need to  ask such questions as narrowing down gives strong indications on what the problem is.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're running out of memory whilst processing these large Word docs, and it's crashing Windows

Comment: I have added the code and debug messages in the question. Thanks for the quick responses. :) Due to this issue i am not able to process the word documents properly.:(

Comment: Will look into the memory usage, but my CPU usage moves more than 90% sometimes during the processing.

Comment: The issue is with instantiating "Application" instance each time of opening the word document. Having the "Application" instance as static member and opening only once solved the issue. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your code bombed Word.  That doesn't happy very often, but Word is rather a large beast and probably contains thousands of bugs that haven't been found yet.  You'll get no help from the exception itself, it happens inside the core code.  Even if you did have the source code for Word, you'd probably still have a helluva time finding out exactly what went wrong.

Word is supported, you can call Microsoft Support.  After you went through the outer support layers, you'll eventually get a support engineer assigned to your problem that knows Word well and can diagnose the cause.  To get through those outer layers, it is very important that you have a good repro available.  The simplest program that can trip this crash on any machine.  Once you got that, have your credit card ready and call them.  They'll give you a URL to upload your repro code.  Be sure to stay in touch with them as your case traverses the support levels, you need to be proactive to ensure they stay on the case.  Count on several weeks if it needs to get all the way.  You'll get your money back if they determine it is a bug in Word instead of your code.

Fwiw, working on getting the simple repro is usually a good way to find out what, if anything, is wrong with your code.  Good luck.

Comment: Excellent answer, plus that creating a good repro might also result into creating a suitable workaround which doesn't trigger the bug. Usually Word can be tamed by pleasing it with some voodoo lines of code.